# C#/Bing Maps Win8.1 - Getting current quadkey(s) as string

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, bing-maps, bing

I have a map which I am trying to add a layer to, which the layer server supports the XYZoomLevel standard, creating a problem.

In order to begin the process of converting a quadkey to an XYZ, I need to get the current quadkey(s) which would be used to render the map outputted to a string and changed every time the key changes. How do I get the quad key as a string value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code that allows you to add a layer, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846495.aspx:

```
MapTileLayer tileLayer = new MapTileLayer();
tileLayer.TileSource = "http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/layers/lidar/{quadkey}.png";
map.TileLayers.Add(tileLayer);
map.SetView(new Location(48.03, -122.42), 11, MapAnimationDuration.None);
```

If you want to use a different uri scheme, you can use an alternative way by using the `GetTileUri()` method of the `MapTileLayer` class, that you will set with your own code to compose the uri. You can then convert the quadkey to xyz or the contrary.

Here a sample code where you use the method:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Bing.Maps.MapTileLayer layer = new Bing.Maps.MapTileLayer();
            layer.GetTileUri += layer_GetTileUri;
            this.map.TileLayers.Add(layer);
        }

        private async void layer_GetTileUri(object sender, Bing.Maps.GetTileUriEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Uri = this.ComposeMyCustomUri(e);
        }
```

Here, `e` is a specific parameter object of type `GetTileUriEventArgs`, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672952.aspx

If you want to go from XYZ to quadkey, you can do it using this C# code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts tile XY coordinates into a QuadKey at a specified level of detail.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tileX">Tile X coordinate.</param>
    /// <param name="tileY">Tile Y coordinate.</param>
    /// <param name="levelOfDetail">Level of detail, from 1 (lowest detail)
    /// to 23 (highest detail).</param>
    /// <returns>A string containing the QuadKey.</returns>
    public static string TileXYToQuadKey(int tileX, int tileY, int levelOfDetail)
    {
        StringBuilder quadKey = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = levelOfDetail; i > 0; i--)
        {
            char digit = '0';
            int mask = 1 << (i - 1);
            if ((tileX & mask) != 0)
            {
                digit++;
            }
            if ((tileY & mask) != 0)
            {
                digit++;
                digit++;
            }
            quadKey.Append(digit);
        }
        return quadKey.ToString();
    }
```

Here is a more complete link from which the code is extracted, MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx